# Facebook post (via graph api) stopped working - is there a limit?

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7

I'm writing a Windows Phone 7 app where I'm posting comments to the users feed on their behalf.  I get the user to auth in the usual way (browser) and get an access token.  All standard stuff that's been working for the last week.  But today the posts have stopped working.  I just get a "Remote Server not found" back from my web call.  Here's the url that I'm using to post (this  used to work perfectly before today):

https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed

Then I add these two form parameters: access_token=...&message=...

I pretty sure the server is up and the access token is good since I can successfully query the users basic profile info using a url like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=...

I have been debugging this flow a bit so my hunch is that Facebook is thinking I'm a spammer and has turned off programmatic posting.  Does this happen?  If y, what's the limit and what's the remedy? If n, any debugging pointers would be helpful, the new facebook docs are very sparse.

Thanks!

Comment: "Remote Server not found" -- this error is related to network issues.

Comment: Yes I realize that the message says server not found.  But I think that's facebooks default error message.  Any clues why it might be happening?

Comment: why do you think it is facebook error message and not network related?

Comment: Because it only stopped working because after i had been posting many times.  Also I can access other data from the graph api (like profile) and this also works if I try it with another user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, hoping others don't waste as much time as I did on this... So while I was debugging my app (that posts to a users feed) I was sending the SAME MESSAGE over and over again. Looks like facebook doesn't let you do that - which makes sense I guess. The "Remote server not found message" strangely enough is actually part of the OAuth 2.0 spec. I get the error but the "Remote Server not found" is pretty confusing...

Comment: There is also a limit to how many message you send per 10 minute period. I believe it is 600.